# Como adicionar novo objeto em posição especifica de array useState Hooks

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Tenho o seguinte estado em hook no Reactjs:

```
const[faixas, setFaixas] = useState([
          {albumId: 1, nome: "nome da musica"}, 
          {albumId: 1, nome: "nome da musica"},
          {albumId: 2, nome: "nome da musica"}
])
const[albuns, setAlbuns] = useState([
         {id: 1, nome: "nome do album"}, 
         {id: 2, nome: "nome do album"}
])
```

Então o que eu estou tentando fazer é, eu tenho um array de faixas que vai me dizer em que álbum ela está pelo albumId. Preciso portanto que no estado **album** eu tenha um array de faixas,então o estado albuns ficaria assim :

```
albuns([{id: 1, nome: "nome do album", 
               faixas: {
                {albumId: 1, nome: "nome da musica"}, 
                {albumId: 1, nome: "nome da musica"}
                       }, 
         {id: 2, nome: "nome do album", 
               faixas: {
                {albumId: 2, nome: "nome da musica"}
                       }]
           )
```

como posso fazer isso? Não consegui usando as alterações do useState:

```
setAlbuns((prev:any) => {
        return [...albuns, faixas.albumId]
      })
```

Não sei como poderia fazer isso,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando `map` para interar em cada item do seu `array` e o `filtro` que vai trazer os dados filtrados do outro `array` pode montar a estrutura como demonstrado na pergunta, exemplo:

```js
function App() {
  const[faixas, setFaixas] = React.useState([
          {albumId: 1, nome: "nome da musica"}, 
          {albumId: 1, nome: "nome da musica"},
          {albumId: 2, nome: "nome da musica"}
  ]);
  const[albuns, setAlbuns] = React.useState([
         {id: 1, nome: "nome do album"}, 
         {id: 2, nome: "nome do album"}
  ]);
  function merge() {
    const result = albuns.map((a) => {
      a.faixas = faixas.filter(x => x.albumId === a.id);
      return a;
    });
    setAlbuns(result);
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    merge();
  },[]);
  return (
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(albuns, null, 1)}</pre>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```